# How do I find the equation of the line that passes through this circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

Find the equation of the line that has x-intercept and  passes through the center of the circle that has equation

$$x^2 + y^2-4x+10y+26=0$$

Comment: Do you know how to find the centre of the circle?

Comment: What do you mean by 'has x-intercept'? Any line with non-zero slop intercepts the x-axis at some point. Could you rephrase your sentence?

Comment: What is the x-intercept of the line??

Answer (score 2):

You would rewrite this equation into the standard form for the equation of a circle. You would do this by completing the squares. For instance,

$x^2+y^2-4x+10y+26=0 \implies (x^2-4x+4)-4+(y^2+10y+25)-25+26=0 \implies (x-2)^2+(y+5)^2 = 3 \implies$

center of the circle is the point $(2,-5)$. Based on your insufficient information (no x-intercept is provided), there are infinitely many lines that pass through the center of the circle. We would have to know the x-intercept in order to solve this problem fully.

Comment: sorry the x-intercept is -3

Comment: Then, using the point-slope form of a line, we have that $y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$. Here, the two points are $(2,-5)$ and $(-3,0)$. So, $m = -1.$ Thus, $y - 0 = -1(x-(-3)) \implies y=-x-3$.

Answer (score 0):

$\left(x−a\right)^2+\left(y−b\right)^2=r^2$ is the **circle equation** with a radius $r$, centered at $\left(a, b\right)$
[image: circle1]
We have the equation $x^2 + y^2-4x+10y+26=0$. We get a circle with center at $\left(2,\:-5\right)$ and radius $r=\sqrt{3}$.

given, the x-intercept is -3. We have
[image]